# LaTeX and pdfLaTeX stop on using the 'fancy' package

Tags: amsmath, texlive, fancyhdr, ubuntu, ieeeconf

I am preparing a document for a conference (APSIPA 2022); the template is available [here](https://www.apsipa2022.org/APSIPA_ASC_2022_Template.zip).

For the camera-ready version, we must use that paper kit to comply with IEEE requirements (adding header and footer).

I was able in another conference template, but I failed in this template.

After debugging several codes in the template, the error is caused by the following two lines:

```
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

The minimum complete sample is given below.

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{APSIPA2021}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[psamsfonts]{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=19mm, bottom=43mm, right=13mm, left=13mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle} {
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Proceedings of 2022 APSIPA Annual Summit and Conference}
    \fancyhead[R]{7-10 November 2022, Chiang Mai, Thailand}

    \fancyfoot[L]{978-616-590-477-3 ©2022 APSIPA}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[R]{APSIPA ASC 2022}
}
\fancypagestyle{fancy} {
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Proceedings of 2022 APSIPA Annual Summit and Conference}
    \fancyhead[R]{7-10 November 2022, Chiang Mai, Thailand}

    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\title{Guidelines for APSIPA ASC 2021 Manuscripts}

\author{%
\authorblockN{%
Thomas Fang Zheng\authorrefmark{1} and
Yanning Zhang\authorrefmark{2}
}
%
\authorblockA{%
\authorrefmark{1}
Tsinghua University, Beijing, China \\
E-mail: xxg@y.edu  Tel/Fax: +86-10-XXXXXXXX}
%
\authorblockA{%
\authorrefmark{2}
Northwestern Polytechnical University, Xi'an, China\\
E-mail: yy@z.edu  Tel/Fax: +86-29-XXXXXXXX}
%
}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
% \pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
  This document is an example of what your final camera-ready
  manuscript to APSIPA ASC 2021 should look like.  Authors are asked
  to conform to the directions reported in this document.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
This document shows guidelines for preparing a final camera-ready
manuscript in the proceedings of APSIPA ASC 2021.  The format here
described allows for a graceful transition to the style required
for that publication.


\section{General Instructions}
Prepare your paper in full-size format on
% US Letter paper (8 1/2 by 11 inches).
A4 paper (210mm by 297mm).  Write the paper in English.


\end{document}
```

If I commented both `% \thispagestyle{firststyle}` and `\pagestyle{fancy}`, pdfLaTeX and LaTeX did not complain. But if one or both exists, it stops (without error message).

The last output is shown below.

```
bagus@m049:Latex$ pdflatex min.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./min.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (./APSIPA2021.cls
Document Class: APSIPA2021 2007/03/05 V1.7a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- Using 210mm x 297mm (a4) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
-- This is a 10 point document.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty

Package amsfonts Warning: The 'psamsfonts' option is obsolete in AMSFonts v3.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsxtra.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./min.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)^Z
[26]+  Stopped                 pdflatex min.tex


bagus@m049:Latex$ pdflatex min.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./min.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (./APSIPA2021.cls
Document Class: APSIPA2021 2007/03/05 V1.7a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- Using 210mm x 297mm (a4) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
-- This is a 10 point document.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty

Package amsfonts Warning: The 'psamsfonts' option is obsolete in AMSFonts v3.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsxtra.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./min.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
```

Log file:

```
This is pdftex, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.8)  9 SEP 2022 13:29
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**atmaja.tex
(./atmaja.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (./APSIPA2021.cls
Document Class: APSIPA2021 2007/03/05 V1.7a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen134
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen135
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count167
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count168
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 3
61.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 210mm x 297mm (a4) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen136
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen137
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen138
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen139
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 719.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 719.
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen140
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen141
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen142
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen143
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen144
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen145
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen146
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen147
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count173
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count176
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count177
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen148
\c@IEEEbiography=\count178
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box45
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2019/05/31 v2.5 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip50
\multirow@cntb=\count179
\multirow@dima=\skip51
\bigstrutjot=\dimen149
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen150
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen151
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count180
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count181
\leftroot@=\count182
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count183
\DOTSCASE@=\count184
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box46
\strutbox@=\box47
\big@size=\dimen152
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count185
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count186
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count187
\dspbrk@lvl=\count188
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count189
\column@=\count190
\maxfields@=\count191
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen153
\alignsep@=\dimen154
\tagshift@=\dimen155
\tagwidth@=\dimen156
\totwidth@=\dimen157
\lineht@=\dimen158
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support


Package amsfonts Warning: The 'psamsfonts' option is obsolete in AMSFonts v3.

\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsxtra.sty
Package: amsxtra 1999/11/15 v1.2c AMS extra commands
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nobreakspace on input line 54.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty
Package: threeparttable 2003/06/13  v 3.0
\@tempboxb=\box48
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen159
\Gin@req@width=\dimen160
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count192
\Gm@cntv=\count193
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count194
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen161
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen162
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen163
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen164
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen165
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen166
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen167
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen168
\Gm@dimlist=\toks21
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip55
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip56
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip57
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip58
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip59
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip60
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip61
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip62
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip63
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count195
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49
)
(./atmaja.aux)
\openout1 = `atmaja.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 34.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box50

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count196
\scratchdimen=\dimen169
\scratchbox=\box51
\nofMPsegments=\count1
```

How can I solve this problem?

My system is [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) with pdfLaTeX version shown above.

Comment: The document compiles fine for me with TeXlive 2022, with or without those lines commented out. I think you posted console output, but the .log file might be more useful for troubleshooting and comparing versions.

Comment: Thanks, @frabjous for the comment. Yes, that is the output command, not the log.  I have added the log file below the console output. It also works with overleaf with Texlive 2022. Mine is TexLive 2019, but it should work too in that version.

Comment: I checked that the tex codes above could be compiled on TexLive 2022 (on Ubuntu 22.04 under multipass) without error. So the problem here is in TexLive 2019.

Comment: don't use `\fancypagestyle{fancy} {` this is defining the fancy pagestyle so that it calls itself. Simply do `\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhead[L]{Proceedings of 2022 APSIPA Annual Summit and Conference}` etc

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer. Could you move your comment to the answer below with more detail? Perhaps, just modify the minimal example above so it just works. I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You use `fancyhdr` version  v3.10. This version doesn't have the possibility to redefine pagestyle `fancy` with `\fancypagestyle`. However, it doesn't give you an error message, but it goes into an infinite recursion loop.

So either change to a recent version of `fancyhdr` (4.0.3 preferably), or change `fancy` to something else.

```
\fancypagestyle{myfancy} {

...

\pagestyle{myfancy}
```